# Toggle Switch can be enabled if a text box is filled in

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to enable a togglebox whenever the user enters in an organisation I.d. I am only new to JS vue so any help would be appreciated.

```
<st-checkbox
      v-model="internalVeterinaryPractice.value.portalEnabled"
      uniqueid="txtPortalEnabled"
      labeltext="Portal Enabled"
      :toggleswitch="true"
    />
```

Comment: This largely depends on what `<st-checkbox>` is, but it could look like `:disabled="/* your condition here */"`. If `<st-checkbox>` doesn't have a `disabled` property, you might have to place that on the actual `<input>` element contained in the `<st-checkbox>`. But if it's part of some library, it most likely has the `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the comment, please check this [quick demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-butterfly-o0fxb?file=/src/App.vue) about how to set `disabled` attribute dynamically.

```
  <div id="app">
    <div>Input: <input v-model="inputVal" /></div>
    <div>
      Checkbox:
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        :disabled="inputVal === ''"
        v-model="checkboxVal"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Related docs: [passing a boolean](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-a-Boolean)